# Symfony Routing - Optional parameters

Tags: php, iphone, json, symfony1

I'm creating a Symfony project that outputs JSON for consumption by an iPhone App.

I have a route set up:

```
notification_json:
  url: /notifications.json
  param: { module: notification, action: index, sf_format: json }
```

This currently lists all notifications (one of my models).

What I'd like to do is add some parameters to this, much like the Twitter API has 'since_id' - so if /notifications.json?since_id=3 was requested, only notifications with an ID higher than 3 would be shown.

I can't see me struggling with the action logic, but the routing for this kind of thing has me scratching my head a little!

Any help would be extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't specify any named parameters (eg `:myparam`) when defining a route in your `routing.yml`, then any parameters you add on when generating the route will be appended as normal GET variables. For example:

```
notification_json:
  url: /notifications.json
  param: { module: notification, action: index, sf_format: json }
```

used with:

```
<?php echo url_for("@notification_json?since_id=3"); ?>
```

will give you:

```
/notifications.json?since_id=3
```

If you add in named parameters into your route, then these will be substituted as normal, with any additional parameters tagged on the end as above, eg:

```
notification_json_test:
  url: /:param1/notifications.json
  param: { module: notification, action: index, sf_format: json }
```

used with:

```
<?php echo url_for("@notification_json?param1=foo&since_id=3"); ?>
```

will give you:

```
/foo/notifications.json?since_id=3
```

Comment: you could also add the parameter ":param1" to your route and give it a default value which is overritten when u specify it:
`notification_json:`
  `url: /:param1/notifications.json`
  `param: { param1: "", module: notification, action: index, sf_format: json }`

Comment: i have a similar issue my route is url:   /recruitmentApply/jobs.:extension where extension can be html or rss i have some trailing  get variables for example "/recruitmentApply/jobs.html?param1=xx&param2=yy ".can any one plaease explain how to do this in symfony 1.4 yml